# Replace row cell of table with row cell of another table using Python

Tags: python, excel, row, cell

In Python, I'm trying to...

look at 2 cells from
a row of a table

and then look at 2 cells from
a row of a second table

and then, if the value of [Table1.RowCell1] is equal to the value of [Table2.RowCell1],
populate [Table2.RowCell2] with [Table1.RowCell2]

What would the code for something like this look like?
Would it require nested for loops?

Here's the code that I have right now:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sj, ["TARGET_FID", field2]) as scursor:
    for srow in scursor:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fl, ["OBJECTID", field]) as ucursor:
            for urow in ucursor:
                if srow[0] == urow[0]:
                    arcpy.AddWarning("You updated FID:" + str(srow[0]))
                    urow[1] = srow[1]
                    ucursor.updateRow(urow)
                    count = count + 1
```

Does this logic make sense?

Comment: Can you share input and expected output samples?

Comment: Are you interested in using pandas?

Comment: @JimParker I could use Pandas but I was interested in using basic Python programming for learning, I guess, without relying on Pandas necessarily. Just so I can understand the logic

Comment: @Alderven I can't at this time but will update the question with that information tomorrow if I still haven't figured it out. Thank you for your help.